# How to implement RAII if the resource acquisition could fail

Tags: c++, raii

I would like to implement a class with the help of RAII. The resources should be acquired in the constructor, but it's possible that the acquistition failed. I'll give an example in the following using FILE:

```
class file {
public:
    file(const char* filename) {
        file_ = fopen(filename, "w+");
        if(!file_) {
          // Okay
        }
        else {
          // ERROR
        }
    }

    ~file() {
        if (fclose(file_)) {
           // ERROR
        }
    }

    void write(const char* str) {
        if (EOF == fputs(str, file_)) {
            throw runtime_error("file write failure");
        }
    }
private:
    FILE* file_;
};
```

So, what's the best way to handle an error which is occurred if fopen returns NULL? Because it's the constructor I can't return also NULL.

I hope somebody can give me a hint how to handle such errors!

Thank you, best regards,

Flasher

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way a constructor can report failure is by throwing an exception.

Destructors, to the contrary, must not throw exceptions (if a destructor throws during stack unwinding, `std::terminate` is called, which ends the program by default).

If destruction fails, you can

- Swallow errors silently
- Abort the program
- Log the error and do either of the above.

If you use RAII correctly, exceptions can traverse your code without damage.

Example here:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

file::file(const char* filename) 
{
    file_ = fopen(filename, "w+");

    if (!file_)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << "Cannot open " << filename << ": "
           << std::strerror(errno);

        throw std::runtime_error(os.str());
    }
}

file::~file()
{
    fclose(file_);
}
```

Note that this code has many bugs: the `fclose` function can fail, and the failure may or may not be related to the closing (eg. some write errors are only reported when flushing at the `close` system call on POSIX systems). Please use iostreams for file I/O in C++, since they provide convenient abstractions over those concerns.

Comment: Additionally, the destructor should *not* throw.

Comment: "what happens if a destructor throws during stack unwinding ?" - `std::terminate()` is called. So throwing from a destructor is about as bad as calling `abort()`.

Comment: -1 Since the response is incorrect, at least for outputting to a file, since you absolutely have to check the status and respond to it after closing the file; if it were just a question of closing the file, `std::ofstream` does the job, and provides a more comfortable and a significantly safer interface than `FILE*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It seems you are right (`man 2 close` provides some explanation). I will add something to the answer.

Comment: @AlexandreC. `man 2 close` doesn't apply to `fclose`, nor to closing an `ofstream`.  In addition to the issues discussed in `man 2 close`, both `FILE` and `filebuf` buffer; the data isn't guaranteed to be transferred to the OS until after closure (or after a flush).  And it's only after that transfer that you can know if the transfer succeeded.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `fclose` will call `close` and fail if the latter fails (dixit `man 3 fclose`). There are also `write` and `fflush` failures too: what I want to point out is that `close` may fail even if the previous write/flushes appeared to have succeeded.

Comment: Missing one important option for the case when destruction fails: Escalate the failure to an instance that is not presently being destructed. Resource destruction is responsibility release. So during destruction, if we cannot clean-up ourselves, somebody else higher up the chain must take over this responsiblity.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name, RAII doesn't necessarily involve resource aquisition;
`std::shared_ptr` doesn't do the `new`, for example.  The name is
historical, and the pattern really concerns cleanup.

In the case of `File`, of course, the "correct" answer is to use
`std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`, and be done with it.  **And** very 
important (at least for output): RAII can only be used for exceptional
clean-up, since you have to verify that the `close` has correctly
finished before leaving the block in the normal case.  As a general
rule, if the close fails, you want to delete the file (and return
`EXIT_FAILURE` from `main`, or do something that will make the error
apparent, and prevent further code from executing on the assumption that
the data were written).  So the only time it would be acceptable to
defer the `close` to a destructor is in a case where you've already
found an error, and are going to delete the file as part of cleanup
anyway.

Generally, output obeys a transaction model, more than an RAII one; I
tend to wrap my `std::ofstream` in an `OutputFile` class, with a
`commit()` function which closes the file, and marks the class as
committed if (and only if) the close succeeds; if the destructor is
called and the file hasn't been committed, the destructor closes the
file, then deletes it.  (Presumably some higher level will catch the
exception and convert it into a `return EXIT_FAILURE` in main.)

Also, IO is a bit exceptional in general.  Normally, if you cannot
create an object, for whatever reason, the constructor should raise an
exception; you don't want "zombie" objects floating around, which can't
be used.  In the case of IO, however, you have to deal with the fact
that the object can become invalid and unusable after construction, even
when construction succeeds.  Since you have to constantly check their
status anyway (after each read on input, and after close on output),
it's often appropriate to just set some internal flag in the object,
which you test.

Comment: "then deletes it" - of course that action depends how the file is being used - if it's used as a log file, then deleting on failure might not be very helpful. But if you're writing a new version of a file to a temporary name, in preparation for atomically renaming it over the original, then deleting is exactly what to do on failure.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  Log files are a special case, I agree; I don't usually bother to check for error status on them---they're "best effort".  In most other cases, however, it's better not to leave an incomplete file laying around.  Similarly, you'll want to `close` or `flush` `std::cout`, in order to propagate the error status out to the return code; but typically, `std::cerr` should be "best effort".  (Note that `cmd orig > tmp && mv tmp orig` is a common idiom under Unix.  With rather unpleasant consequences if a write failure doesn't result in an error return status.)